# BroadcastReceiver и Activity LifeCycle

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver

Есть некоторый `BroadcastReceiver`, который регистрируется в методе `onStart` активити и деактивируется (unregister) в методе `onStop`.

Есть сервис, который посылает интент, который должен поймать данный `BroadcastReceiver` и вывести данные из него в активити, полем класса которой он является.

Если сервис отошлет интент в момент поворота экрана, то есть в то время, когда ресивер деактивируется, но еще не зарегистрируется, то данные из сервиса до активити уже не дойдут (аналогичная ситуация произойдет, если в процессе загрузки информации пользователь банально свернет приложение).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно обработать эту ситуацию.

---

PS. Может быть, в этом случае подойдет как-либо другой способ коммуникации между сервисом и активити. Если быть более конкретным и упросить задачу, то она выглядит так:

В активити нажимаем кнопку, запускается сервис, который загружает текст из интернета и отдает этот текст обратно в активити, в которой он отображается. Главная цель - гарантированно доставить данные из сервиса до активити.

Задача довольно распространенная, уверен, что многие ее уже решали, но почему-то не могу найти хорошего решения.

Comment: Ресивер нужно зарегестрировать через манифест вашего приложения, тогда он будет всегда срабатывать, а не только когда активити работает.

Comment: @pavlofff, В таком случае, если я правильно понимаю, ресивер нужно реализовать в отдельном классе, но при этом доступа к полям активити у него не будет, а мне нужно из ресивера обновлять активити.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, вы можете ресивер не в активити подключать и содержать, а в фрагменте с `setRetainInstance(true);` - это команда будет препятствовать пересозданию фрагмента при поворотах экрана. Это рекомендуемая гуглом практика для храняния данных в активити. Думаю и для вашей задачи это решение подойдёт

---

Вам, в общем, надо хранить где-то состояние (например да, в сервисе или фрагменте этом) и при воостановлении активити это состояние отображать. Вообще для этого всего есть архитекурное решение типа MVP MVC etc). Его можно самостоятельно реализовать или либы юзать. Mosby, Moxy, много их. Суть такова - актвити при восстановлении запрашивает сервис/презентер/синглтон а текущем состоянии (данные есть/нет/в процессе загрузки) и отображает состояние. При этом сущность для хранения состояния, конечно, не должна уничтожаться при повороте. Такой сущностью может быть помянутый выше фрагмент, синглтон, сервис, презентер. Серебряной пули нет. Модно сейчас MVP подход использовать. Лично я Mosby либу использую. В презентере состояние - в методах жизненного цикла активити запрашиваю у презентера его и отображаю.

Comment: Если я буду использовать retain-фрагменты, то необходимость в сервисе, в моем случае, вообще отпадет. Да, я знаю про headless-фрагменты, но что-то мне не очень нравится это решение.

Comment: @Burence, дополнил ответ

Comment: Задача эта сугубо учебная, рассчитана на новичков и поставлена таким образом, что решить ее нужно только инструментами из коробки, поэтому я и думаю, что есть какой-то довольно простой и более-менее правильный способ, о котором я не знаю. На практике-то да, можно (*нужно*) использовать хорошие сторонние решения, но эту задачу хотелось бы решить в рамках стандартного SDK. Вариант с синглтоном пока мне импонирует больше всего, но, возможно кто-то предложит другие варианты. Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: @Burence, попробуйте ServiceConnction заюзать. Т.е. у вас будет колбэк соединения с сервисом. А в сервисе все данные+состояние. Вот в этом колбэке и получайте из экзепляра сервиса всё что нужно. Так и ресивер будет совсем не нужен.

Comment: Насколько я понял, от байндинга в данной ситуации толку не будет. С помощью этого механизма можно из активити вызывать методы сервиса, **но не наоборот**. Мне же нужно оповестить активити из сервиса, после того, как он загрузил данные..

Comment: Ну, тогда да, ресивер тоже нужен. Если даже пропустит сообщение то данные то всё же отобразить пропущенные

Comment: Загруженные данные можно сохранить в сервисе, это да. Но если активити пропустит сообщение от сервиса, то она и не узнает о том, что данные загружены. Как забрать данные при байндинге - понятно, а как вот оповестить активити, что эти данные готовы, при условии, что активити пропустила сообщение от сервиса - непонятно.

Comment: Всё просто. Пусть активити при подключении к сервису отображает сохранённые в нем данные. Так у неё всегда самые последние и актуальные будут

Comment: Хм, что-то я об этом не подумал.